# Native BigInt and Intl.NumberFormat for accurate currency calculations and display?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bigint, currency-formatting

As you probably know, `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004` in JavaScript. Limited precision when dealing with money can be a problem. To overcome this, one could use [BigInt](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2018/05/bigint.html), which obviously requires integer values.

Instead of dollars as base unit and cents as decimal fraction (e.g. `0.10` for ¢10) it is easy to use cents as base unit (`10` for ¢10) to make it integer-only.

However, when presented to a user, you probably want to show the value in dollars, not cents. But you can't divide `BigInt` by `Number`:

```
> BigInt(10) / 100
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions
```

On the other hand, [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) does not seem to provide a way to do something like this either. So, what can you do instead?

A straightforward way thanks to base 10 would be to insert a period at position -2 into the number string and pass that to the formatter:

```
let formatter = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD"
})
let s = (BigInt(10) + BigInt(20)).toString() // "30"
s = s.padStart(2, "0")                       // zero-pad single digit (if input 0..9)
s = s.slice(0, -2) + "." + s.slice(-2)       // ".30"
formatter.format(s)                          // "$0.30"
```

Is this the way to go? Are there better solutions?

I'm aware that `format(0.30000000000000004)` also results in `$0.30` because of rounding but this is rather a general question about BigInt + UI.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with BigInt.  Do you use numbers with more than 15 significant digits?

Comment: My question is of theoretical nature, but looking at financial reports such as of the US government, figures in the trillions are possibly something that you want to do some math with and format it for display on a website.

Comment: The problem with your example is that when you pass the string value into `.format` it creates a Number out of it, so you lose the precision you had in your BigInts.  I don't see a similar formatting function for BigInt so I would imagine you need to add the $ yourself using string manipulation similar to how you do the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide a `bigint` value by `100n` (bigint 100) to get the right number of dollars:

```js
function toDollarsString(total) {
  const dollars = total / 100n;
  const cents = total % 100n;
  return `\$${dollars}.${cents}`;
}

console.log(toDollarsString(30n));
console.log(toDollarsString(1024n));
```

Comment: Good point and the modulo operation works with BigInt too, as you show. However, the goal is to let `Intl.NumberFormatter` take care of the locale-specific currency formatting. While it accepts BigInt meanwhile, there does not seem to be a way to tell it that the unit is cents (×100), nor to pass in `dollars` and `cents` separately.

Comment: A `scale` option was proposed (see https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/334) but essentially rejected because of backward compatibility issues. They want to wait for the Decimal proposal. They also want to add a new option to directly work with a string input instead of implicitly casting the passed value to a limited-precision number. However, it will probably take several more years before it becomes available in browsers etc.

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says, explicitly convert your `BigInt` to a `Number`. Don't use an intermediate string like you're doing:

```js
let toDisplayValue = n => Number(n) / 100;

console.log(toDisplayValue(BigInt(1234567)));
console.log(toDisplayValue(BigInt(45)));
```

Comment: This assumes that `n` is representable by the Number type, which is not necessarily the case: `Number(9007199254740993n)/100 // 90071992547409.92`. Interestingly, Intl appears to use Float64 internally for formatting, because even with my hack using a string as input you end up with `"$90,071,992,547,409.94"`...

Comment: When that's not the case, your only real options are string manipulation, or some external "big number" library.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the BigInt implementation. It's rather the lack of large number support elsewhere. I didn't expect Intl.NumberFormat to be number based at all to be honest. Not sure what reasons there might be, as it seems to be doable based on strings alone - except for the implicit rounding maybe?